# Why are ftplugins ignored?

Tags: plugin-system

I'm trying to understand why my ftplugin isn't loaded. To get at least some understanding what's going on, I've tried

```
strace -e file gvim test.cpp |& grep ftplugin
```

But this gave me empty output, although `:set ft` says `cpp`. I do have lots of files in `/usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin`, and `cpp.vim` is among them. My `$VIMRUNTIME` is `/usr/share/vim/vim74`. So apparently Vim doesn't even try to load any `ftplugin`, although it does load e.g. `tarPlugin.vim` and others in the `plugin` directory (not `ftplugin`).

What could be wrong in my config that would make Vim not even consider any `ftplugin`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If you want to strace gvim, you need to make sure, that it does not fork.

2) filetype plugins are only loaded if your .vimrc contains a line like `filetype plugin indent on` (with or without indent, depending if you want indent plugins to be loaded as well.)

Read the help at `:h filetype-plugin-on` and the following paragraphs.

Comment: 1) can be dealt with by `strace -f`. But anyway, gvim only forks after loading the plugins. As for 2), why do I need `indent` if simple `filetype plugin on` would do (as given by the help page you reference)?

Comment: 1) That is not correct. gvim loads ftplugins whenever a new buffer is loaded, so it is not true, that this only happens before gvim forks. 2) this depends on whether or not you want customized indenting to apply per filetype